# Where Not Group Of Where Statements

Tags: laravel

I would like do where this is not true, the opposite of this query, but whereNot doesn't exist to reverse the boolean.

```
->where([
    ['item_type', 'App\Models\Extra'],
    ['item_id', 1]  
])
```

Comment: use `doesntHave`

Comment: I tried that but "has() and whereHas() do not support MorphTo relationships."

Comment: then you can try `!=` in your `where` query

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the negation of your query like this:

```
->where([
    ['item_type', '!=', 'App\Models\Extra'],
    ['item_id', '!=', 1]  
])
```

If you try to get the result immidiatly after that query add `->get()` at the end, like this:

```
->where([
    ['item_type', '!=', 'App\Models\Extra'],
    ['item_id', '!=', 1]  
])->get();
```

Comment: I tried that, but the boolean needs to be reversed for the two where statements together, otherwise if item_type is equal to App\Models\User and item_id is 1, it returns false because item_id would match but item_type wouldn't

Comment: I got it working with the following: `->where(function ($query) {
      $query->where('item_type', '!=', 'App\Models\Extra');
      $query->orWhere('item_id', '!=', 1);
  })`

Comment: @jdawg well you did not say that it is an or statement, but anyways congrats